# timestamp of inserts with SYSMAN differs from timestamps of other users in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have tried below table created but issue is in the current_timestamp value getting inserted in the table.
for all inserts with any other user timestamp is IST but for inserts with "SYSMAN" timestamp is GMT 
how can i update the below table creation to accomodate the same

```
CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."DB_LOGIN_AUDIT" 
   (    "AUDIT_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "USERNAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "OSUSER" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "TERMINAL" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "IP" VARCHAR2(64 BYTE), 
    "MODULE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "UPDATE_TIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "REMARKS" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "DB_LOGIN_AUDIT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("AUDIT_ID")

   )  ;
```

Comment: Cant you make it SYSTIMESTAMP ?

Comment: As CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is sensitive to the time zone.

Answer (score 0):

just do this

```
update SYSTEM.DB_LOGIN_AUDIT
set UPDATE_TIMESTAMP=UPDATE_TIMESTAMP-360/1440;
```

I think this will update all your timestamp with GMT

Comment: Was my suggestion helpful??? please let me know if you have some more things in your mind...